# sqlalchemy: Why create a sessionmaker before assign it to a Session object?

Tags: python, session, orm, sqlalchemy

Why I always need to do that in 2 steps in SqlAlchemy?

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm

engine = sa.create_engine(<dbPath>, echo=True)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
my_session = Session()
```

Why I cannot do it in one shot like (it's could be more simple, no?) :

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm

engine = sa.create_engine(<dbPath>, echo=True)
Session = orm.Session(bind=engine)
```

Answer (score 20):

The reason `sessionmaker()` exists is so that the various "configurational" arguments it requires only need to be set up in one place, instead of repeating "bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False", etc. over and over again.  Additionally, `sessionmaker()` provides an "updateable" interface, such that you can set it up somewhere in your application:

```
session = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False)
```

but then later, when you know what database you're talking to, you can add configuration to it:

```
session.configure(bind=create_engine("some engine"))
```

It also serves as a "callable" to pass to the very common `scoped_session()` construct:

```
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

With all of that said, these are just conventions that the documentation refers to so that a consistent "how to use" story is presented.   There's no reason you can't use the constructor directly if that is more convenient, and I use the `Session()` constructor all the time.  It's just that in a non-trivial application, you will probably end up sticking that constructor call to `Session()` inside some kind of callable function anyway, `sessionmaker()` serves as a default for that callable.

Comment: I was finishing up my answer when this popped up.  I just wanted to add that I once always wondered & hated this too... until I realized my problem was only with the naming -- not what is actually going on.  When I paid attention to what was really happening, and looked at stuff under the hood... it's just a standard factory pattern -- one that saves a lot of work for my and for Python.

Comment: Why would you not just call the config on the `session = Session()` once, (without sessionmaker) then inject session where needed instead of repeatedly creating a new session just to get an instance with the same config?  I typically see the factory pattern as allowing you to not being tied to a specific implementation (like if there were different types of Session classes, BigSession, SmallSession, etc...).  However, it looks like there's only one type of Session in SQL alchemy, why a factory?

Comment: a Session is a facade around a (usually) single database transaction on single database connection.   it's a stateful object that is only good for doing one thing at a time.    most kinds of applications need to handle any number of connections / transactions simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

In the most general sense, the Session establishes all conversations with the database and represents a “holding zone” for all the objects which you’ve loaded or associated with it during its lifespan. It provides the entrypoint to acquire a Query object, which sends queries to the database using the Session object’s current database connection, populating result rows into objects that are then stored in the Session, inside a structure called the Identity Map - a data structure that maintains unique copies of each object, where “unique” means “only one object with a particular primary key”.

Try to `pprint` and see whats inside;

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(my_session)
```

Here's the rest of the story: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/session.html